# Gedits gedit-latex-plugin not working correctly

Tags: gedit, plugins, latex

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 yesterday and am now working on setting things up correctly. I am having a problem with gedit-latex-plugin for gedit. I can install it and enable it, and I get the extra menus and all that. I have installed rubber, but if I try to compile a file, nothing happens.

If I select e.g. LaTeX -> PDF, nothing happens. Not even verbose output on the bottom panel.

I am very new to Ubuntu so maybe I am overlooking something.

Comment: What compiler is gedit-latex-plugin configured to use?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have got some tex environment (like texlive) installed (if you're not sure, try executing `tex --version` or `latex --version` in a terminal).
If so, you might want to check the directory where you saved your .tex file and see if (upon executing latex) any files were created.
There should at least be a log file which you could check.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this on one of my .tex files and it compiled as usual. Compiling it in texmaker also works, it is just that it doesn't work in gedit.

Comment: Just realized that I can easily use the embedded terminal to build the documents. Would be nice to use the gedit-latex-plugin commands tho.